# Android Navigation Drawer can't click on one item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have a really interesting problem with my Navigator menu.
I have no idea why... But I can click on any item from my menu, I don't want to say I click and nothing happened. I really want to say I can't click on any item, all my menu it's like a big image.
I've try to make a new project witch already have Navigation Drawer Activity, of course it works.. but when I've try to copy that code and put on mine.. I have the same problem and vice versa, I've try to put my code into a new project with Navigation Drawer Activity, but again... I can't click on any item.
Here it's one [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNkgo.jpg) with my aplication.

Here it's my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ArrayList<Trail> arrayTrail;
ListView listViewTrails;
ArrayList<Wonder> arrayWonders1;
ArrayList<Wonder> arrayWonders2;
ArrayList<Wonder> arrayWonders3;
ArrayList<Wonder> arrayWonders4;
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    arrayWonders1 = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayWonders2 = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayWonders3 = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayWonders4 = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayWonders1.add(new Wonder("https://risehighershinebrighter.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/magic-of-blue-universe-images.jpg", "Ceva", "100"));
    arrayWonders1.add(new Wonder("http://i765.photobucket.com/albums/xx291/just-meller/national%20geografic/Birds-national-geographic-6873734-1600-1200.jpg", "Ceva", "20"));
    arrayWonders2.add(new Wonder("hhttp://www.freestockphotos.name/wallpaper-original/wallpapers/download-images-of-gentle-dogs-6866.jpg", "Ceva", "400"));
    arrayWonders2.add(new Wonder("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg", "Ceva", "200"));
    arrayWonders3.add(new Wonder("http://hdwallnpics.com/wp-content/gallery/hd-tiger-images/tigers-wallpapers-hd.jpg", "Ceva", "100"));
    arrayWonders3.add(new Wonder("http://imgscenter.com/images/2014/09/13/6-autumn-nature-sandbox-images_2053316.jpg", "Ceva", "100"));
    arrayWonders4.add(new Wonder("http://www.tollywooddaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/HORIZONTAL-BABY-HIGHRES-EMPTY.jpg", "Ceva", "100"));
    arrayWonders4.add(new Wonder("http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg", "Ceva", "100"));


    arrayTrail = new ArrayList<>();
    Trail audi = new Trail("http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg", "Paris", "Popular Destination", "htrhetgftrwfrec", "Story", arrayWonders1);
    Trail opel = new Trail("http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg", "Romania", "Popular Destination", "fewfwefwefWgfeg", "Story", arrayWonders2);
    Trail mercedes = new Trail("http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg", "Italia", "Popular Destination", "gtrhrthtrhrw", "Story", arrayWonders3);
    Trail ferrari = new Trail("http://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/multimedia/images/moons/images/PIA07759.jpg", "Roma", "Popular Destination", "dajfuisndfisndfs", "Story", arrayWonders4);
    Trail fiesta = new Trail("http://www.quicksprout.com/images/foggygoldengatebridge.jpg", "Bucuresti", "Popular Destination", "regehgtrhrjhjy", "Story", arrayWonders1);
    Trail porshe = new Trail("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rZmCIp0C-hQ/Tx6aCFeweoI/AAAAAAAAAnQ/WqIEVBTIzRk/s1600/Cool-Tiger-Wallpaper-1920x1080-HD.jpg", "Luxemburg", "Popular Destination", "Ffdsjifsdfmskodmf", "Story", arrayWonders2);

    arrayTrail.add(audi);
    arrayTrail.add(opel);
    arrayTrail.add(mercedes);
    arrayTrail.add(ferrari);
    arrayTrail.add(fiesta);
    arrayTrail.add(porshe);

    listViewTrails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_trails);
    ListTailsAdapter adapter = new ListTailsAdapter(this, arrayTrail);
    listViewTrails.setAdapter(adapter);
    listViewTrails.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Trail selectedTrail = arrayTrail.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("trail", selectedTrail);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.main_menu_search) {
        ArrayList<Trail> trails = arrayTrail;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("trailsSearch", trails);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

}

And here it Navigation Drawer Fragment class:

```
    public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.categori_1),
                        getString(R.string.categori_2),
                        getString(R.string.categori_3),
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return getActivity().getActionBar();
    }

    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

So if anyone of you guys have any idea... Please tell me, I really need to fix it as soon as possible and in this moment I don't have any idea how..

Thx for your help :)

Comment: This can happen if your DrawerLayout doesn't have it's child Views z-ordered correctly. Make sure your ListView (or whatever container ViewGroup it is in) is listed last in your layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me

```
public class MyDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

// other code
    super.setContentView(fullLayout);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout3);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), menuItem.getTitle().toString(),
             //       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
                update();
                // Handle the camera action
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Manage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_cantect) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutCantect.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            //navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_5_reasons).setChecked(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```